# Populating SQLiteDB with initial values

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

My app uses a database, it comes pre-populated with about 50 values. I'm accomplishing this by doing about 50 db.execSQL("INSERT INTO.... statements in the onCreate section of my DbHelper class.

I was wondering if there was a more ideal way to handle the insertion of initial values or if this was perfectly acceptable.

Comment: How is the format on the initial values? Are they in a list? Text-document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more than one value set at the same time into a single table:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (column_a, column_b)
VALUES (val_1, val2), (val_3, val_4), etc
```

This will perform much faster and be more concise!

Also you may want to consider loading this data from a properties file or similar so it's more easily changed should those initial values ever vary.

Comment: That too; also pack the inserts into a transaction; this is the main performance killer with Android and SQLite.

Comment: thanks, that cleans it up a bit. I did try loading values from an array resource file and running through a loop... I couldn't seem to get it to work, is that something that is possible/recommended?

Comment: The nice part about having the resource file is that it's not as difficult to change a non-code file.  Also you can easily use a different resource when you're doing your testing to try things that would normally be difficult to set up.